# -ing form after "can't help but"

Tags: verbs

Should I use -ing form after *can't help but*? Some examples from the web that appear conflicting to me:

> *I can't help but* **feel** there will be people who will be thinking
>   about what happened.

or

> *I can't help but* **feeling** ripped off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as "I feel", "I can't help but feel".  You *could* use "feeling" if you reworded the sentence: "I can't help but have the feeling that I was ripped off" or "I can't help but have the feeling of being ripped off".  The "can't help but" part does not change the form of the verb.  You could just take those three words out and have the same meaning (or at least pretty close).

Comment: So the second example is incorrect? It should be "I can't help but feel ripped off?"

Comment: @Gruber: That is correct.

Comment: You could also say "I can't help feeling ripped off" if you want to use "feeling" as a gerund instead of a noun.

Answer (score 1):

"Cant' help but do anything" and "can't help doing it" mean the same thing, the former being somewhat more formal, IMO. "Can't help but doing" is incorrect.